# POSTGRESQL: How to update column from resulted table?

Tags: postgresql

For extracting data on the basis of common id with other tables i applied `Select` queryso that i can calculate: **credit**,**debit** and **balance**:

```
SELECT account_id as account_id,account_move_line.account_id as id, 
    COALESCE(SUM(debit),0) - COALESCE(SUM(credit), 0) as balance,
    COALESCE(SUM(debit), 0) as expense_income, 
    COALESCE(SUM(debit), 0) as debit, COALESCE(SUM(credit), 0) as credit 
FROM account_move as account_move_line__move_id,account_move_line
WHERE account_id IN (SELECT id FROM account_account WHERE user_type_id IN (SELECT id from account_account_type WHERE internal_group IN ('expense','income')))  
    AND ("account_move_line"."move_id"="account_move_line__move_id"."id") 
    AND (("account_move_line__move_id"."state" = 'posted')  ) 

GROUP BY account_id,account_move_line.account_id
```

Result i am getting which is perfect:

[image]

What i am trying to achieve is to fill **expense_income** column with those credit and debit who does not have 0 values in the resulted **Table**. Currently i am able to fill only 1st by using **as** which i believe is not a way. I had also followed some posts for combing those logic but i got failed. I also apologies for bad English.

posts that i followed:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/153174/postgresql-update-table-row-values-by-grouped-column

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/153174/postgresql-update-table-row-values-by-grouped-column

Comment: You have `COALESCE(SUM(debit), 0) as expense_income` which returns correct data in your case. You don't have involved `credit` column here. So what is your problem?

Comment: i want to fill expense_income column with both dredit and debit values

Comment: COALESCE(SUM(debit), 0) as expense_income , COALESCE(SUM(credit), 0) as expense_income together i get error expense_income is already used  like that

Comment: Error apppears if i write alogether the above comment in the query: psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "expense_income" specified more than once

Comment: alternatively cud be what if i assign string value for the debit and credit having values

Comment: for example, if `debit` is 10 and `credit` is 20, what value you want in `expense_income` ?

Comment: No, debit column has either 0 or max value and same as for credit as shown in picture. I want to fill expense column with greater than 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I corectly understand, you need `greatest` value between  debit and credit. If so, then you can use this:

```
SELECT account_id as account_id,account_move_line.account_id as id, 
COALESCE(SUM(debit),0) - COALESCE(SUM(credit), 0) as balance,
greatest(COALESCE(SUM(debit), 0), COALESCE(SUM(credit), 0)) AS expense_income,


CASE WHEN COALESCE(SUM(debit),0) > COALESCE(SUM(credit), 0) THEN 'debit'
ELSE 'credit' END AS from_where_the_value_comming,

COALESCE(SUM(debit), 0) as debit, COALESCE(SUM(credit), 0) as credit 
FROM account_move as account_move_line__move_id,account_move_line
WHERE account_id IN (SELECT id FROM account_account WHERE user_type_id IN (SELECT id from account_account_type WHERE internal_group IN ('expense','income')))  
    AND ("account_move_line"."move_id"="account_move_line__move_id"."id") 
    AND (("account_move_line__move_id"."state" = 'posted')  ) 

GROUP BY account_id,account_move_line.account_id
```

Comment: yes that is what i wanted. Can it also be possible to give column name from where the value is comming up? e.g debit was zero and credit was 102 so in output expense_income got value 102 from column: credit

Comment: It would be great as i am still trying

Comment: can it be possible? it would be great if u can add a column and place a string values telling from which column that greatest value arrived

Comment: Do you need change column name? then you need dynamic sql, but I think adding one another column, which detects  from where the value is comming up.

Comment: one more thing can it be possible to get group by only "from_where_the_value_comming" rather account_id and account_move_line.account_id ? it would be great those result will have a summary as indicating only debit and credit

Comment: group by only "from_where_the_value_comming" rather account_id and account_move_line.account_id would give totally different result.

Comment: i did by placing from_where_the_value_comming and removing other but i got error that aggregate functions are not allowed in GROUP BY

Comment: Yes, that's correct,  aggregate functions are not allowed in GROUP BY. You can achieve using sub query... but I think it will better, if you open another topic, where You post your table data and final   result, what You want to get.